# Show that a group, given by a presentation, is countable & reduced with a nontrivial element of infinite height

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-presentation, p-groups, infinite-groups

This is part of **Exercise 4.3.7** of Robinson's *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*. According to [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3AReduced%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainfinite%20height&p=10), it is new to MSE.

*[NB: I did not include the [combinatorial-group-theory](/questions/tagged/combinatorial-group-theory) tag for a reason.]*

### The Details:

Presentations are defined in a previous chapter of Robinson's book; however, many of the tools available in combinatorial group theory are not discussed; I cannot, for instance, use Tietze transformations in this exercise.

The tools available are:

- Basic facts about free groups.
- Basic facts about reduced words.
- The normal form of an element.
- The projective property of free groups.
- [von Dyck's Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/vonDycksTheorem.html).
- Basic facts about finitely presentated groups; *viz.*, B.H. Neumann's theorem and P. Hall's theorem.

This list is not exhaustive. There's a whole section of the book on varieties but I doubt it's relevant.

---

On page 94, *ibid.*,

> An element $g$ of an abelian group $G$ is said to be *divisible* in $G$ by a positive integer $m$ if $g=mg_1$ for some $g_1$ in $G$. If $p^h$ is the largest power of the prime $p$ dividing $g$, then $h$ is called the *$p$-height* of $g$ in $G$: should $g$ be divisible by every power of $p$, we say that $g$ has *infinite $p$-height* in $G$. [. . .]
>
> An abelian group $G$ is said to be *divisible* if each element is divisible by every positive integer. This is equivalent to saying that each element of $G$ has infinite $p$-height for all primes $p$.

On page 96, *ibid.*,

> An abelian group is said to be *reduced* if it has no nontrivial divisible subgroups.

On page 106, *ibid.*,

> In speaking of the *height* of an element in an abelian $p$-group $G$ we always mean the $p$-height.

### The Question:

> Let $G$ be generated by $x_1, x_2,\dots$ subject to the defining relations $px_1=0$, $p^ix_{i+1}=x_1$ and $x_i+x_j=x_j+x_i$. Prove that $G$ is a countable reduced abelian $p$-group containing a nonzero element of infinite height.

### Thoughts:

Since $x_i+x_j=x_j+x_i$, clearly $G$ is abelian. We can conclude that $G$ is a $p$-group because each of its generators is a $p$-th power multiple of $x_1$ by $p^ix_{i+1}=x_1$, and $x_1$ has order $p$ by $px_1=0$. That much is easy.

---

A naïve guess would be that $G$ is countable because it can be generated by countably many generators. I do not hold this view, simply out of caution; I don't know how to go about proving it yet. My suspicion is that this guess, if true, would allow a proof by contradiction.

---

Showing $G$ is reduced might also be done by contradiction. To this end, suppose $H\le G$ is divisible. Then each nontrivial $h\in H$ would permit, for lack of a better way of putting it, "too many prime divisors $q\neq p$".

---

As for the element $h$ of infinite height, I'm not sure. It has to follow from $px_1=0$ and $p^ix_{i+1}=x_1$, I suppose, and, again, for lack of a better way of putting it, perhaps $h$ is a "limit of the $x_i$ as $i$ tends to infinity" - but this is *nonsense*.

---

A word on the multifaceted nature of this question: I think demonstrating the properties of $G$ here might each be fairly simple and that they're eluding me because I am overthinking them; and as such, I think asking a separate question for each property would lead to tedious repetition and diminishing returns.

---

I think I could answer this myself if I gave it some more time, especially because my current degree is in combinatorial group theory. It's just that I've given it over a week now and I'm losing momentum in the book because of it.

The type of answer I'm hoping for is a set of strong hints or a full solution.

---

Please help :)

Comment: (Rewritten, because some of the statements in the earlier version were wrong!) Just a couple of quick comments. Yes, every group with a countable set of generators is countable. That is basically because every element of the group can be expressed a word of finite length in the generators. Yes, the fact that $p^{i}x_{i+1}=x_1$
proves that $x_1$ is divisible by $p^i$ for all $i$, so it has infinite $p$-height. Reducibility is a bit harder.

Comment: That a countably generated group is countable follows because every element of the group $\langle X\rangle$ is a *finite* product of elements of $X$ and their inverses. that means that the cardinality of such a group is at most $\aleph_0|X|$, so for $X$ countable, the generated group is countable.

Comment: To show reducibility: none of elements $x_k$, $k\gt 1$, is a $p$th power. You can verify this by mapping $G$ to the cyclic group of order $p^k$, sending $x_k$ to the generator, and all other $x_i$ to the trivial element. If $x_k$ were a $p$th power, then its image would be a $p$th power in that group, which it plainly isn't. Thus, no subgroup containing any $x_k$ with $k\gt 1$ can be divisible. That only leaves $\langle x_1\rangle$ and its subgroups, but this is cyclic of order $p$ and hence not divisible.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin To complete the proof of reducibility, you would need to show that every subgroup contains some $x_k$ for $k>1$. The subgroup $\langle x_2+px_3\rangle$ does not obviously do so. (A minor modification of your proof does work though.)

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: Good point. Thanks.

Comment: For any fixed $k\gt 1$, you can map the subgroup generated by $x_1,\ldots,x_k$ to the cyclic group of order $p^{k+1}$ by sending $x_k$ to the generator, $x_{k-1}$ to the $p$th power of the generator, etc. Any subgroup not contained in $\langle x_1\rangle$ contains a nontrivial element in such a subgroup, but under the map it lands in an element of finite height, so the subgroup is not divisible.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That should work. A much smaller modification is to let $\sum a_ix_i$ be some element in the subgroup, and just map to the quotient you described, where $k$ is such that $a_k\neq 0$. OK, $p$th powers might exist, but since this is a cyclic $p$-group, *some* $p$-power won't work. This might involve fiddling with the generators though to avoid this all elements of order $p$ are the same problem, so perhaps your method is better.

Comment: I can fix that by noting that the intersection of the kernels of all of your quotients is $\langle x_1\rangle$, so any element outside of that has non-trivial image under one of these homomorphisms.

Comment: Since $G/\langle x_1\rangle\cong\langle
\bar{x_2}\rangle\oplus\langle \bar{x_3}\rangle\oplus\ldots$ is
reduced then $G$ is also reduced. Here $\bar{x_i}=x_i+\langle x_1\rangle$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven: I think this gets rid of the complications (similar to @kabenyuk's): if $H$ is a divisible subgroup of $G$, then $pH$ is divisible. But $pG\cong \oplus_{i=1}^{\infty}C_{p^i}$ (which is straightforward to to establish, I think) is reduced, so $pH\leq pG$ is trivial, and since $H$ is divisible, this means $H$ is trivial.